# Agregar class en input select Swal2

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo editar el class de un input select de swal2. Al momento de generar un swal2 con select este no me lo muestra ya que necesita la siguiente class `browser-default custom-select select-sm` . editando el archivo `js`?

```
Swal.fire({
              title: 'Selecciona algo',
              input: 'select',
              allowOutsideClick: false,
              inputOptions: inputOptions,
              inputValidator: function(result) {
                  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                      if (result) {
                          resolve();
                      } else {
                          reject('You need to select something!');
                      }
                  });
              }
          }).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            
          })
```

Comment: Agregue un style y funciono =/

Comment: ¿Y si respondes a tu pregunta escribiendo el style y poniendo como tal la solución? Eso podría ayudar en el futuro a otras personas.

Answer (score 1):

Swall tiene la capacidad de pasar class con `customClass`

```
Swal.fire({
  ...
  customClass: {
    container: 'container-class',
    popup: 'popup-class',
    header: 'header-class',
    title: 'title-class',
    closeButton: 'close-button-class',
    content: 'content-class',
    input: 'input-class',
    actions: 'actions-class',
    footer: 'footer-class'
  }
  ...
}
```

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/1440